# GULP: gulp is not defined

Tags: npm, gulp

As shown in the screen shot below I am not able to run `gulp` to concat the JavaScript files. Its saying that `gulp is not defined`.

I have tried the following commands:

```
npm install -g gulp
npm install gulp
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

I have also set the environment variables as following:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Python27;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp;
```

[image]

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');  
var rename = require('gulp-rename');  
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');  


//script paths
var jsFiles = 'scripts/*.js',  
    jsDest = 'dist/scripts';

gulp.task('scripts', function() {  
    return gulp.src(jsFiles)
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest));
});
```

Comment: try installing gulp-cli package from npm

Comment: `var gulp = require('gulp');`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you just need to install and require `gulp` *locally*, you probably only installed it globally

At the command line

```
cd <project-root> && npm install --save-dev gulp
```

In your gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
```

this is a different dependency than the command line dependency (that you installed globally). More specifically, it is the same NPM package, but the command line program will execute code usually from a different entry point in the NPM package then what require('X') will return.

If we go to the package.json file in the Gulp project on Github, it will tell the whole story:

```
{
  "name": "gulp",
  "description": "The streaming build system",
  "version": "3.9.1",
  "homepage": "http://gulpjs.com",
  "repository": "gulpjs/gulp",
  "author": "Fractal <contact@wearefractal.com> (http://wearefractal.com/)",
  "tags": [ ],
  "files": [ 
     // ...
   ],
  "bin": {
    "gulp": "./bin/gulp.js"
  },
  "man": "gulp.1",
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     // ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "marked-man --name gulp docs/CLI.md > gulp.1",
    "lint": "eslint . && jscs *.js bin/ lib/ test/",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.9"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

so at the command line:

```
$ gulp default
```

will execute this:

```
     "bin": {
        "gulp": "./bin/gulp.js"
      },
```

on the other hand, require('gulp') in your code will return the value of this:

```
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/index.js
```

normally we see this in a package.json file as:

```
"main": "index.js"
```

but since this is the default, they just omitted it (which is dumb IMO, better to be explicit, but they aren't the first project I have seen take the lame shorthand route.).

Answer (score 0):

Its occurs on Windows and usually one of the following fixes it:

- If you didn't, run npm install gulp on the project folder, even if
  you have gulp installed globally.
- Normally, It isn't a problem on Windows, but it could be a issue with
  the PATH. The package will try to get the PATH from the environment,
  but you can override it by adding exec_args to your gulp settings.
  For example, on Ubuntu:

  "exec_args": {
        "path": "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
      }

Hope It will be OK.

Source: https://github.com/NicoSantangelo/sublime-gulp/issues/12